# compile C in CentOS face error: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c, linux, centos

I compiled C in CentOS and face this error:

> cc -c -o obj/BT.o BT.c -I./include -I/usr/dialogic/inc
> cc -o BT obj/BT.o obj/util.o -I./include -I/usr/dialogic/inc -L/usr /dialogic/lib
>
> obj/BT.o: In function 'main':
>
> BT.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `gc_Start'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [BT] Error 1

I already linked to library  `-L/usr /dialogic/lib` but i don't know why it does not link when create binary file
Please, any one can suggest me something ?

Comment: The `-L` option is to tell the linker where to *search* for libraries, it doesn't actually link with any libraries, for that you need the `-l` (lower-case L) option.

Comment: You've only specified a link *path* - you also need to specify the library via `-lname` where `name` signifies `libname.a`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is my lib, it's dynamic lib: `libgc.so`, I already used `-llibgc` options, it show error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibgc`. This is my command: ` cc -o rrbt obj/BT.o obj/util.o -I./include -I/usr/dialogic/inc -L/usr/dialogic/lib -llibgc`

Comment: I just use `-lgc` it show error: `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/dialogic/lib/libgc.so when searching for -lgc`. is that by incompatible lib with current gcc?

Comment: I just fix it. I move code to CentOS 32 bit, it compile fine, may by lib incompatible in CenOS 64 bit. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

check if you had saved your.c file and also check of spelling of the functions' definition and their calls .

Comment: While this answer suggests the basics, IMHO, it does not answer the question.